# spark 1.5.2 left outer join not working

Tags: apache-spark

I have  two dataframes

- df1 with 500 columns, one of which is id(StringType) and number of records 10 million
- df2 with 4 columns, one of which is id(StringType) and other 3 columns(say x, y, z) name match with 3 columns of df1(same name, i.e. x, y, z), it contain 0.2 million records

I want to do left join, hence join df must have 10 millions records with 500 columns

```
  df1.join(df2, "id", "left_outer")
```

it is giving me error
error: type mismatch:

```
  found   : String("id")
  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

what to do, and when i'm trying

it is giving me org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: join condition 'id' of type string is not a boolean.

what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a column reference - as mentioned in the error message. You can do that by importing `spark.implicits._` and using `$` to alias the `id` column:

import df1.sparkSession.implicits._
   df1.join(df2, $"id", "left_outer")